# Clave por defecto en MongoDB Atlas

Tags: python, mongodb

tengo un problema intentando conectarme a un cluster en MongoDB Atlas, he intentado con `root` `admin` `pass` y no funciona.

`'mongodb+srv://root:<password>@cluster.mongodb.net/more_params'`

cuando ejecuto mi codigo python salta el siguiente error

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth Authentication failed.

Comment: Hola, deberias comentar que version de mongo estas utilizando y que version de python. Por otro lado, me imagino que habras quitado los "< >", digamos que debe quedar asi : 
  mongodb+srv://usuario:password@cluster.mongodb.net/more_params

Comment: Hola @MarianoMoyano ya lo resolvi, bastaba con crear un nuevo usuario

Comment: hola @qwerty acepta tu respuesta, asi cierras el tema. saludos y disfrutar

Answer (score 0):

Basta con crear un nuevo usuario en el apartado de `Security > Database access`, despues en `Add new user` y le otorgamos los privilegios que deseemos. Despues agregamos el usuario y la clave correspondiente en la constante
`DB = 'mongodb+srv://nuevo_usuario:nueva_clave@cluster.mongodb.net/more_params'`